# SSL + proxy_pass = 404?

Tags: ssl, nginx, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy

Greatings for everyone.
Having trouble with configurating `nginx-1.13.8` on `Windows Server`.
When added SSL on `reverse_proxy` i receive `404`

Working configuration (http):

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.3:80;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Configuration with ssl:

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         ../cert/certcombined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     ../cert/private_rsa.key;


    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://192.168.0.3:80;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

`192.168.0.3` is apache on linux
Sorry for `"broken english"`

Comment: Add these two directives to start with...: `access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;` `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;`

Comment: I dont know why, but when i add `access` and `error` log paths everything works.... 0_0

Comment: You can remove `ssl on;`. This directive is obsolete as of nginx 1.15, in favour of the adding ssl to your listen directive. I would also add these to your http block `ssl_session_timeout 5m; ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;` and these to your server block `ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5; keepalive_timeout 90;`

Comment: As i said i use `nginx 1.13.8`, but thank you for hint with additional configuration